# How sencha touch 2.0 differs from other frameworks?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

There are more framework is available to develop the HTML5 application like jQuery mobile, Sencha touch.

So, how sencha touch differs form other framework? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If it is about jQuery mobile vs Sencha touch, Miami coders has it [here](http://miamicoder.com/2011/sencha-touch-or-jquery-mobile-read-this-before-you-make-a-decision/)

Answer (score 1):

Well some features the Sencha Touch offers is

```
1. Sencha Architect IDE to code and visually create apps.
2. Sencha Cmd which provides tools for building and deploying applications.
3. Sencha provides some native apis for use.
4. Rich UI out of the box.
5. Built on top of the webkit engine. So supports only those browsers at the moment.
6. Built in MVC structure
....
```

The features can go on like this. There are other libraries out there which can be used but they you might need to use other libraries like backbone etc to provide some of the functionalites in Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have a link where you can find the difference between sencha touch and other frame work.
This link will Educate you about Sencha , Phonegap & Rhomobile Framework.

Hope it will work for you.

http://www.smartsourcingglobal.com/2012/07/31/cross-device-mobile-application-development-comparison-phonegap-rhomobile-sencha-3/